# What is this pattern called, and how should it be tested?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns

In brief: What is the pattern called in the following code, and how should it be tested?

The purpose of the code is to encapsulates a number of actions on a zip file (written in C#, although the pattern is language independent):

```
public class ZipProcessor
{
    public ZipProcessor(string zipFilePath) { ... }

    public void Process()
    {
        this.ExtractZip();
        this.StepOne();
        this.StepTwo();
        this.StepThree();
        this.CompressZip();
    }

    private void ExtractZip() { ... }
    private void CompressZip() { ... }
    private void StepOne() { ... }
    private void StepTwo() { ... }
    private void StepThree() { ... }
}
```

The actual class has around 6 steps, and each step is a short method, 5-15 lines long. The order of the steps is not important, but Extract and Compress must always come first and last respectively. Also, `StepTwo` takes much longer to run than the rest of the steps.

The following are options I can think of for testing the class:

- Only call the public `Process` method, and only check the result of one step in each test method (**pro**: clean, **con**: slow, because each test method calls `StepTwo`, which is slow, even though it doesn't care about the result of `StepTwo`)
- Test the private steps directly using an accessor or wrapper (**pro**: simple, clear relation to what is run during a test and what is actually tested, **con**: still slow: extracts and compresses multiple times, hacky: need to use a private accessor or dynamic wrapper, or make the steps `internal` in order to access them)
- Have only one test method that calls a bunch of smaller helper test methods (**pro**: fast, models the class more closely, **con**: violates "one assert per test method", would still need to run multiple times for different scenarios, ex. `StepOne` has different behavior based on input)

Comment: That is called the ***(OOPP) Object Oriented Procedural Pattern*** ha ... ha

Comment: I would split up the Extraction/Compression into its' own class, test those functions individually. What does step 1-3 have to do with archive extraction/compression? You could place those steps into separate class and test those methods individually. A "processor" class could call the two or more classes and you could mock out the methods accordingly.

Comment: Having each step as a separate class would result it far too many classes. Also, perhaps I should have left out Extract, Compress since that seems to muddle the example. All they do is call into another library to perform the actions; there is nothing to test in them.

Comment: I see, I wasn't suggesting step per class, I don't know what your steps do so I wouldn't know how to design it. I would write tests first to design it. I would still have integration tests on your class that wraps the zip library (7zip or whatever it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a pattern reflected here, but you could rewrite your code to use the Strategy or Chain of Responsibility patterns, as pointed out Paul Michalik. As is, you basically just have a custom workflow defined for your application's needs.  Using the Chain of Responsibility pattern, each step would be its own class which you could test independently.  You may want to then write an integration test which ensures the whole process works end-to-end (component or acceptance level test).

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the discussion, but this is a Sergeant Method.

A quick google returns "We call the bigger method here as 'sergeant' method, which basically calls other private methods and marshaling them. It may have bits and pieces of code here and there. Each of these private methods is about one particular thing. This promotes cohesion and makes sergeant method read like comments".

As for how you can test it - your example presumably violates SRP because you have a zip compressor/decompressor (one thing) and then step1/2/3. You could extract the private method invocations into other classes and mock those for your test.

I disagree that Chain-of-Responsibility makes much sense here - the compressor shouldn't need to know about the decompressor (unless they're the same class) or the reason why it's doing the decompression. The processing classes (Step1/2/3) shouldn't care that the data they're working with was compressed before, etc.

The strategy pattern doesn't really make sense either - just because you can swap the implementation of extractZip or compressZip doesn't mean you have a strategy pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to split it into 2+ classes - ExtractZip/Compress and process or 1 class ExtractZip/Compress with delegate in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Depending on your testing scenario you can derive from `ProcessorMock` (or implement it if its an interface) and override the methods not relevant to test by proper stubs. However, usually, the more flexible pattern for such cases is [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_responsibility_pattern)...

Comment: This is definitely not Strategy.

Comment: Not as he implemented it, but that apparently are pattern he's looking for.